# Is there a way to obtain the program counter value for a thread in CUDA? By modifying device driver or Compiler?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I would like to implement a runtime that allows a thread in GPU to obtain the value of the program counter. I have searched in Cuda Programming Guide and [PTX guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#set-of-simt-multiprocessors:%7E:text=thread%2C%20including%20a-,program%20counter,-and%20call%20stack) as well.

> With Independent Thread Scheduling, the GPU maintains execution state per thread, including a program counter and call stack, and can yield execution at a per-thread granularity.

May I know where the value of the program counter is stored? In what register assigned to that thread? Is there a way that allows the thread to obtain the value of the program counter?

**If a thread cannot do it, then can we modify the driver, or compiler, or using inline assembly to achieve that?**

Answer (score 1):

> May I know where the value of the program counter is stored? In what
> register assigned to that thread?

The PTX virtual machine instruction only exposes a [limited number](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#special-registers) of special registers.

At the time of writing, that doesn't include the program counter or the stack frame, as far as I am aware. This appears to be true whether the GPU architecture is using a block wide PC or an independent per-thread PC.

> Is there a way that allows the thread to obtain the value of the
> program counter?

Not as far as I am aware.

Comment: Is the program counter register supported in the latest PTX? If not, could you please tell me if there is a way that allows a thread/warp of threads to obtain the corresponding PC value? I am thinking about the persistent thread approach, where 1 thread per SM, is there a way for that persistent thread to obtain the PC value?

Comment: As my answer says: The current PTX instruction set (linked) doesn't include anything related to the PC. If it isn't exposed in PTX, then there isn't a way to do it in user code.

Comment: Thanks! May I know if it is possible to do access the PC by modifying the driver, or the compiler? If yes, may I know if you could provide me with some hints?

Comment: No there is no public information and you should assume it isn’t possible